# Python parse large db over 4gb

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse a `db` file with python that is over 4 gb.

Example from the db file:

```
% Tags relating to '217.89.104.48 - 217.89.104.63'
% RIPE-USER-RESOURCE

inetnum:        194.243.227.240 - 194.243.227.255
netname:        PRINCESINDUSTRIEALIMENTARI
remarks:        INFRA-AW
descr:          PRINCES INDUSTRIE ALIMENTARI
descr:          Provider Local Registry
descr:          BB IBS
country:        IT
admin-c:        DUMY-RIPE
tech-c:         DUMY-RIPE
status:         ASSIGNED PA
notify:         order.manager2@telecomitalia.it
mnt-by:         INTERB-MNT
changed:        unread@ripe.net 20000101
source:         RIPE
remarks:        ****************************
remarks:        * THIS OBJECT IS MODIFIED
remarks:        * Please note that all data that is generally regarded as personal
remarks:        * data has been removed from this object.
remarks:        * To view the original object, please query the RIPE Database at:
remarks:        * http://www.ripe.net/whois
remarks:        ****************************

% Tags relating to '194.243.227.240 - 194.243.227.255'
% RIPE-USER-RESOURCE

inetnum:        194.16.216.176 - 194.16.216.183
netname:        SE-CARLSTEINS
descr:          CARLSTEINS TRAFIK AB
org:            ORG-CTA17-RIPE
country:        SE
admin-c:        DUMY-RIPE
tech-c:         DUMY-RIPE
status:         ASSIGNED PA
notify:         mntripe@telia.net
mnt-by:         TELIANET-LIR
changed:        unread@ripe.net 20000101
source:         RIPE
remarks:        ****************************
remarks:        * THIS OBJECT IS MODIFIED
remarks:        * Please note that all data that is generally regarded as personal
remarks:        * data has been removed from this object.
remarks:        * To view the original object, please query the RIPE Database at:
remarks:        * http://www.ripe.net/whois
remarks:        ****************************
```

I want to parse each block starting with `% Tags relating to`

and out of the block I want to extract the `inetnum` and first `descr`

This is what I got so far: **(Updated)**

```
import re

with open('test.db', "r") as f:
    content = f.read()

    r = re.compile(r''       
            'descr:\s+(.*?)\n',        
            re.IGNORECASE)  
    res = r.findall(content)
    print res
```

Comment: don't use a greedy match. Use `.*?` instead

Comment: Ok for `descr`, but what are `route` and `origin` ?

Comment: updated the code, but not sure how to loop through it as "blocks" meaning only grabbing whats inside of each `% RIPE-USER-RESOURCE`

Answer (score 1):

as it's over 4gb file you don't want to read all the file in one time by using f.read()

but using the file object as an iterator (when you iterate on a file you get one line after the other)

the following [genererator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators) should do the job

```
def parse(filename):
    current= None
    for l in open(filename):
        if l.startswith("% Tags relating to"):
            if current is not None:
                yield current
            current = {}

        elif l.startswith("inetnum:"):
            current["inetnum"] =  l.split(":",1)[1].strip()
        elif l.startswith("descr") and not "descr" in current:
            current["descr"] =  l.split(":",1)[1].strip()
    if current is not None:
        yield current
```

and you can use it as the following

```
for record in parse("test.db"):
    print (record)
```

result on the test file:

```
{'inetnum': '194.243.227.240 - 194.243.227.255', 'descr': 'PRINCES INDUSTRIE ALIMENTARI'}
{'inetnum': '194.16.216.176 - 194.16.216.183', 'descr': 'CARLSTEINS TRAFIK AB'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get **first** descr :

```
r = re.compile(r''
        'descr:\s+(.*?)\n(?:descr:.*\n)*',
        re.IGNORECASE)
```

If you want inetnum and first descr :

```
[ a + b for (a,b) in re.compile(r''
        '(?:descr:\s+(.*?)\n(?:descr:.*\n)*)|(?:inetnum:\s+(.*?)\n)',
        re.IGNORECASE) ]
```

I must admit I make no use of `% Tags relating to`, and that I suppose that all `descr` are consecutive.

Comment: I need to find a way to loop through each block based on `% Tags relating to` because some "blocks" have multiple `descr`

Comment: @Alosyius The proposed code keeps only first descr provided they are all adjacent. Did you try it ?